# Run a process suspended, but modified some content of the image of it in memory before continue

Tags: c, winapi

I need help for do this:
I have a executable that have some null terminated string inside it.
I want to execute it suspended, but before continue, I need put in the first character of buffer a NULL, for let it unusable.  What steps I need to do.?

I only have this first three lines:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
CreateProcess(0, "app.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

But in next, what I need for read the memory of the image of process and modify it ?

I need use ReadProcessMemory? Then, how i get the base address, what type of buffer i need?

Any help please for do this task.

Comment: You are aware that you're fighting Windows when you do this, and that you will be detected by most anti-virus/malware software as a virus?

Comment: This won't actually make the string unusable or unreadable. As long as someone figures out what you're doing, they can just skip the first character and read the rest of the string. Which is easy if they attach a debugger. What is the point of this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why don't you make the operation at the build time of the executable "app.exe" itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use ReadProcessMemory of pi.hProcess (which is handle of your newly created executable)
But before you try read/write there, you MUST understand, that when you are creating process in suspended state, it is not fully loaded (your buffers, code, etc.. could not be loaded yet!) But you can manually load PE into memory, you'll have to write your own PE Loader. Also, base address will be same. e.g if your executable (which is going to be executed in suspended mode) has base address at 0x400000, then it will be same for new process.

Good luck.

EDIT:
About what type of buffer you need, you have to somehow "flag" that buffer to get the actual address. (Hint: padding with random characters).